# Print all data of table using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am using dirPagination.js for pagination of table in angular js. I want to print all the data present in the Table. I have tried some ways but I am only able to print current page data. Can anyone let me know to print all data present in table having pagination.

Please let the question get answered instead of marking duplicate or useless question, better help.

Comment: can u make a simple plunkr so we can help

Comment: @PanosK Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/7OfKd7xbRHkzFIPlpWS7?p=preview

Comment: ok probably i didnt fully understood the question where you want to print all the data

Comment: @PanosK, As shown in the fiddle, i m able to print only first page, but my requirement is to print all 10 pages.

Comment: items per page input isnt supposed to work if you set it 100? you want to print 100 records even if your item per page is set to 10?

Comment: Yes. i want to print 100 (all the data in table) records even if item per page is set to 10.

Comment: ok change this line 
<li dir-paginate="meal in perman  = ( meals | filter:q ) | orderBy: order?'key':'-key' | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">{{ meal.key + ': ' +meal.val }}</li>


to this

                <li dir-paginate="meal in perman  = ( meals | filter:q ) | orderBy: order?'key':'-key' | itemsPerPage: 100" current-page="currentPage">{{ meal.key + ': ' +meal.val }}</li>

just wondering why you want to do this ?

Comment: @PanosK, I think you didn't understand my question and just answering for the sake of points. Even I know that, if the itemperpage is 100 will print all the data  but my requirement is different. I want to show 10 line and want to print 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very Simple. Here i have done printing of all the data of table.

```
var popupWin;
$scope.printDiv = function(divName,loclist) {
    console.log(divName)
    console.log(loclist.finalarr)
    localStorage.setItem('itemKey', JSON.stringify(loclist.finalarr));
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html ng-app="dumb"><head><link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="script/lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> <script src="script/lib/angular.js"></script><script src="script/lib/ngStorage.min.js"></script></head><body onload="window.print();window.close()" ng-controller="dumbconr"><table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table bulk_action" style="font-size:10px;"><thead><tr class="headings"> <th>S.No</th><th>Tool</th><th>Action Done</th><th>User</th><th>Assigned To</th><th>FollowUp Date</th><th>Contact Name</th><th>Company Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>City</th><th>Product</th><th>Dealing Product</th><th>Result</th><th>Action to be done</th><th>Next FollowUp</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="even pointer" ng-repeat="data in lli"><td>{{$index+1}}</td><td>{{data.tool}}</td><td>{{data.followups.actiondone}}</td><td>{{data.empid}}</td><td>{{data.followups.assignedto}}</td><td>{{data.followups.followup| date: "dd MMM yyyy"}}</td><td>{{data.name}}</td><td>{{data.firmname}}</td><td>{{data.contact}}</td><td><span ng-if="data.city">{{data.city}}<span><span ng-if="!data.city">-<span></td><td>{{data.product}}</td><td>{{data.dproduct}}</td><td>{{data.followups.result}}</td><td>{{data.followups.nextaction}}</td><td>{{data.followups.nextfollowup | date: "dd MMM yyyy"}}</td></tr></tbody></table><script>var app=angular.module("dumb", ["ngStorage"]).controller("dumbconr",function($scope, $localStorage, $rootScope){ $rootScope.lli=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemKey"));})</script></body></html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Here

1. loclist is the array that need to print.
2. i have created the html page in the controller and based on that i am rendering the data and also checking the required conditions.
3. Using the Localstorage get and set method able to get data.